# Calorie Calculator

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have developed a calorie-tracker webpage and would appreciate some feedback on it. I'm particularly interested in optimizing performance, improving code readability, and ensuring best practices are followed.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='eng'>
    <head>
      <title>FITIFY | Fitness Tracker</title>
      <!--CSS Styling-->
      <style>
        h1{
            color: gold;
            font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
            font-weight: bolder;
        }
        h2, h3{
           color: white;
           margin: 6%;
           text-align: center;
           font-family: 'Instrument Sans', sans-serif;          
           font-size: 40px;
           font-weight: bold;
        }
        h5{
          background: linear-gradient(to right, red, orange, yellow, green, blue, indigo, violet);
          -webkit-background-clip: text;
          -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
          background-clip: text;
        }
        a{
            text-decoration: none;
            color: white;
            margin: 3%;
        }
        .nav-brand{
            margin: 1%;
            color: white;
        }
        .btn{
            background-color: #19376D;
        }
        .btn:hover{
            background-color: green;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .nav-links{
            width: 40%;
            margin-right: 0%;
        }
        .dropdown{
            display: inline-block;
        }
        .main-box{
            background: linear-gradient(to bottom right,#3d97ce 0%,#12debb 100%);
            width: 100%;
            height: 90vh;
            border-bottom: solid black 3px;
            margin-top: 6%;
            position: relative;
        }
        .main-text-box{
            float: left;
            width: 50%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        #main-para{
          color: white;
          text-align: left;
          margin: 2% 2% 2% 10%;
          font-size: 22px;
          visibility: hidden;
          font-weight: 400;
        }
        .main-image-box{
            float: right;
            width: 50%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        #main-img{
            width: 80%;
            height: 80%;   
            margin: 5%;
            border:white solid 3px;
        }
        #to-features{
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
            border: solid 2.5px;
            border-image-slice: 1;
            border-image-source: linear-gradient(to right, red, orange, yellow, green, blue, indigo, violet);
            width: 10%;
            height: 10%;
            position: absolute;
            margin: 0% 40% 0% 20%;
            bottom: 10%;
            font-family: 'Instrument Sans', sans-serif;          
            font-size: 20px;
            font-weight: bold;
          }
        .feature-box{
            background: linear-gradient(to top right,#3d97ce 0%,#12debb 100%);
            background-size: cover; 
            height: auto;
          }
        .card{
            color: black;
            background-color: white;
            width: 21%;
            height: 250px;
            margin: 14% 2% 10% 2%;
        }
        .row{
            margin-right: 0%;
        }
        .cards-btn{
          background-color: black;
          color: white;
          border: solid 3px;
          border-image-slice: 1;
          border-image-source: linear-gradient(to right, red, orange, yellow, green, blue, indigo, violet);
          padding: 2%;
          margin: 50px 10% 2% 20%;
          font-family: 'Instrument Sans', sans-serif;          
          font-size: 13px;
          font-weight: bold;
        }
        .cards-btn:hover{
          color: green;
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
            h1{
              font-size: 4rem;
            }
            h2{
              font-size: 5rem;
            }
            a{
                margin: 3%;
                font-size: 2.5vw;
            }
            .nav-links{
                margin: 0%;
                width: 70%;
            }
            .btn{
                font-size: 2.5vw;
                margin-right: 1%;
            }
            .main-box{
                margin-top: 8%;
                height: 100vh;
            }
            .main-text-box{
                width: 100%;
            }
            #main-para{
                font-size: 6vw;
            }
            .main-image-box{
                display: none;
            }
            #to-features{
                width: 30%;
                height: 5%;
                padding: 1%;
                margin: 0% 20% 15% 35%;
                font-size: 2rem;
                font-weight: bolder;
            }
            .card{
                width: 35%;
                height: 30%;
                margin: 15% 10% 5% 35%;
                font-size: 1.4rem;
            }
            .cards-btn{
                margin: 5% 5% 2% 30%;
            }
            #goal-btn{
                margin-left: 25%;
            }
        }
        @media screen and (min-width: 1800px) and (max-width: 2600px) {  /* 4k */
            h1{
              font-size: 6rem;
            }
            h2{
              font-size: 5rem;
              font-weight: bolder;
            }
            a{
                margin: 5%;
                font-size: 3rem;
            }
            .nav-links{
                margin: 0%;
                width: 55%;
            }
            .btn{
                font-size: 3rem;
                margin-right: 10%;
            }
            .main-box{
                margin-top: 6%;
                height: 100vh;
            }
            #main-para{
                font-size: 60px;
            }
            #to-features{
                width: 20%;
                height: 9%;
                padding: 1%;
                font-size: 40px;
                margin: 10% 0% 0% 15%;
            }
            .card{
                width: 20%;
                height: 250px;
                margin: 15% 3% 10% 2%;
            }
            #goal-btn{
                margin-left: 10%;
            }
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <header>
          <nav class="navbar bg-dark fixed-top" data-bs-theme="dark">
              <div class="nav-brand">
                  <h1>FITIFY</h1>
              </div>
              <div class="nav-links">
                  <a href="./index.html">HOME</a>
                  <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                      FEATURES
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu gap-1 p-2 rounded-3 mx-0 shadow w-220px" data-bs-theme="light">
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item rounded-2" href="./bmi.html">BMI CALCULATOR</a></li>
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item rounded-2" href="./calories.html">TRACK CALORIES</a></li>
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item rounded-2" href="./goal.html">KNOW YOUR GOAL</a></li>
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item rounded-2" href="./basic_redirect.html">STORE YOUR DETAILS</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <a href="./about.html">ABOUT US</a>
                  <a href="./contacts.html">CONTACT US</a>
                </div>
              </nav>
            </header>
        <main>
          <div class="main-box">
            <div class="main-text-box">
              <h2>Transform yourself today.</h2>
              <p id="main-para">"Welcome to Fitify, your ultimate fitness companion! We are dedicated to helping you on your fitness journey by providing powerful tools to track your progress. With our user-friendly interface achieving your health and fitness goals has never been easier. Join our community today and take the first step towards a healthier, fitter you!"</p>
              <button id="to-features">GET FIT</button>
            </div>
            <div class="main-image-box">
              <img src="./nutri.webp" id="main-img" alt="Display Image">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="feature-box">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="card">
                    <i class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-dumbbell"></i>
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">CALCULATE YOUR BMI</h5>
                      <p class="card-text">Calculate your Body Mass Index (BMI) to know your health status right away.</p><br>
                      <a href="./bmi.html" class="cards-btn">CALCULATE</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="card">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-utensils"></i>
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">TRACK YOUR CALORIES</h5>
                      <p class="card-text">Track your calories for the day and know how much you consumed today.</p>
                      <a href="./calories.html" class="cards-btn">TRACK NOW</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="card">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-person-dress"></i>
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">YOUR IDEAL WEIGHT</h5>
                      <p class="card-text">Calculate your ideal weight by entering your measurements.</p><br>
                      <a href="./goal.html" class="cards-btn" id="goal-btn">KNOW YOUR GOAL</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="card">
                      <i class="fa-solid fa-info"></i>
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">STORE YOUR BASIC DETAILS</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Keep a log of your basic information in our secure database.</p>
                        <a href="./basic_redirect.html" class="cards-btn">STORE DETAILS</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
        </main>          
      <script>
          const button = document.getElementById('to-features');
          window.onload = function() {
            var para = document.getElementById("main-para");
            var para_text = para.innerHTML;
            var speed = 15; 
            var i = 0;
            para.innerHTML = "";
            function typeWriter_para() {
              if (i< para_text.length) {
                para.innerHTML += para_text.charAt(i);
                i++;
                setTimeout(typeWriter_para, speed);
              }
            }
            setTimeout(typeWriter_para, 100); // Delay before starting the paragraph animation
            para.style.visibility = "visible"; // Make the paragraph visible
          };
          const feature_box = document.querySelector('.feature-box');
          button.addEventListener('click', function(){
            feature_box.scrollIntoView();
          });
      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**LIVE SITE URL:** [Click Here](https://fitify-fitness-tracker.netlify.app/calories.html)

Please feel free to provide any feedback, suggestions, or improvements you think would enhance the code quality and maintainability of my project. Thank you in advance for your time and valuable insights!

Comment: `<html lang='eng'>` looks wrong: we must use the IANA registered value which always takes identifiers from ISO-639 part 1 code (i.e. `'en'`) in preference to any value from part 2 or part 3, according to BCP-47.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 1 General Issues

#### 1.1 Markup Validation

As the comments state, `eng` is not a valid value for the `lang` attribute. [W3C Validation Service](https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea) will flag with a red flag.

#### 1.2 Indents

Your idents differ. Sometimes you use 2 spaces for indents and on other parts, you sued 4 spaces for indents. YOu should use the tab only and decide between 2 or 4 but do not mix them.

#### 1.3 Loigcal Gaps

You used no logical gaps which hurt readability. your code reads similar to a book with no paragraphs but all text in one block and without any punctuation.

Use logical gaps to spread elements apart and give a visual difference between elements that do not directly belong to each other. This allows developers to read more easily and recognize specific modules or element groups. As an example, you could have split the single cards from each other.

#### 1.4 Linebreaks

You used no linebreak which also makes text hard to read. Split text within a paragraph to a new line to fit even a smaller screen. Right now any developer has to horizontally scroll to read the text.

#### 1.5 Comments

You only used one COmment and the above style tag to show that CSS follows. The comment there is redundant. Anyone who will read the code knows that a `style` tag contains CSS.

You could use a comment as a headline if you use more then one CSS to headline a logical code block but it is unnecessary in your case.

### 2 Head Element

#### 2.1 Character Set

While it is still valid not to declare a character set, I would recommend you always use `<meta charset="utf-8">` to ensure that the same character set is used as you programmed in.

#### 2.2 Styling

You chose head-style for your CSS. This overall does the job but will hurt both performance and readability.

##### 2.2.1 Performance

Since you have a single file and HTML as well as CSS and JS are single-threaded, everything will run and read synchronously. That means, that first the style is read before the document can even start to render the document. The rendering of the document with that is delayed.

A performant solution would be to push the CSS into its own CSS file and load the CSS file as an external file. That way, the CSS can even be cached which will improve loading times at the second request.

##### 2.2.2 Readability

As for readability, a dedicated external file will always win. It is easier to read the CSS in a different file where I explicitly expect it to be CSS. On the other hand, I do not have to check where the CSS start and where it ends. Which also makes the HTML code shorter.

##### 2.2.3 Best Practice

The best practice when developing with an RWD (Responsive Web Design) approach is to start mobile first and then use styles for higher and higher screens that will overwrite previous stylings.

You sued 2 media queries one for 1200px or below and one for between 1800 and 2600px. You have no queries for between 1200-1800px and none to address screens higher the 2600px. That is harder to read and is confusing as any developer will search for the missing queries and/or will have to scroll between the entire CSS to see which style would apply on a certain width.

#### 2.3 JavaScript

##### 2.3.1 Performance

Same as with the CSS you should move the JS to an external file and allow the usage of running it into a second thread independent from the HTML. You should then declare it within the head element so it will be read already during the start and reduce the time it needs to execute the script.

###### window.onload()

This issue only matters if you keep the script at the end of the body. That event trigger is redundant or useless. A script at the end of the body will only execute when the entire document is already read and parsed. There is no need to wait for the `onload` event anymore.

##### 2.3.2 Readability

As said before, you miss logical gaps which make your code harder to read. You also miss sufficient commenting to explain what you trying to do.

the next issue is following code fragment:

```js
var i = 0;
para.innerHTML = "";
function typeWriter_para() {
  if (i< para_text.length) {
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter_para, speed);
  }
}
```

in the `if` condition you are referencing a variable called `i`. As a quick sidenote in that configuration, the variable `i` is not readable. On the other hand, you use a function to create and copy the behavior of a `for` loop.

##### 2.3.3 innerHTML

You should not use `innerHTML` anymore. It has 2 issues, for one it is slow as it needs the DOM to prepare and on the other hand, it poses a security risk (XSS injection).
Since you only try to get text, use `textContent` instead.

##### 2.3.4 Conventions

Conventions are a good way to increase readability and to work with other developers as well as maintenance.

###### 2.3.4.1 Constants and variables

You should differentiate constants and variables from each other by writing const NAMES as capital.

Declare constants at the very top of the document or if you use an `onload` event at the top within the `onload` event. Your `const feature_box` is declared somewhere in the mid-end.

Use a constant when you expect something not to change within your script. Noticeably in the variable `var para = document.getElementById("main-para");` I would expect that the element does not change and as such a constant would have been more appropriate.

###### 2.3.4.2 Naming

You should use names that are self-explaining. Names are used to be self-explaining to developers and as such must be readable. At no point should they be chosen for efficiency to save a few bytes. The word `para` is an actual word coming from Latin and means "side". It is not the best choice to choose a short word for a paragraph.

##### 2.3.5 Best Practice

###### 2.3.5.1 let vs var

You have to choices to declare a variable either `let` or `var`. In modern JS I would recommend always using `let` unless you understand the difference and explicitly need the options that `var` would give you.

###### 2.3.5.2 onload

In modern JS you do not use event triggers such as `onload` or `onlick` (all events starting with `on`). The issue here is, that you can only have one event and will always overwrite the previous event.

The modern practice is to append events by using `addEventListener`.

As such you should change:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  // your function
}
```

to this modern approach:

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  // your function
})
```

### 3 Body

#### 3.1 Navbar

```html
<div class="nav-brand">
  <h1>FITIFY</h1>
</div>
```

That is not an element I would expect within a navbar as it has no navigational purpose. More appropriate would be the placement within the `header` element outside of the navbar.

As such your container `<div class="nav-links">` will be obsolete as `nav` as a container can take over the task.

It is not incorrect to use `ul` as a container for a list of links but IMHO it would be more appropriate for `menu` which behaves the same. The reason why it is not incorrect in technical terms is conflicting documentation between Mozilla (official documentation and WHATWG founder) with the WHATWG specifications. Those conflicts are caused because HTML5 and CSS3 are not officially specified in technical terms by the W3C but are proposed in the form of recommendations by WHATWG.

#### 3.2 Main

You contain your content within the `main` element by pushing them into logical containers by using `div`. A `section` would be more appropriate as a semantic container than a `div`